# Newly added column missing from Available Destination Columns in ADO NET Destination

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I need to add a column to an ETL process. Completed all steps successfully except the last one - `ADO NET Destination` (the "Insert Specs" element on the left).

[image: SSIS conditional split]

The new column appears just fine in the `Conditional Split`, both as a source column and destination column.

In the `ADO NET Destination` ("Insert Specs") the new column only appears on the left in the "`Available Input Columns`" and it's missing on the right ("`Available Destination Columns`").

[image: ADO NET Destination mappings]

I know for sure my new column is present in the destination table. Did I miss a step along the way?

---

**Update:**
What's also interesting is that when I hover over the ADO NET Destination element I get this warning:

A new column with name `sold_price` has been added to the external database table. Use advanced editor to refresh available destination columns if needed.

[image: ADO NET Destination - new column added]

Comment: Any chance the ADO .NET Destination you're pointing to doesn't have the new column available? If you're positive you're pointing at the correct destination, and you're not working in Offline mode, close the package and re-open it. This will force the designer to revalidate all of the metadata

Comment: Thanks, @billinkc. Already tried that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The view above is for "**Edit**".

The instructions however ask for the "**Advanced Editor**".

[image: SSIS advanced editor in Visual Studio]

There is a "**Refresh**" button at the bottom of the **Advanced Editor**. Clicking this button adds the new column to the "**Available Destination Columns**" box.

[image: SSIS advanced editor view in Visual Studio]

Comment: Any idea how to update the available input columns? I.E when you add a new column to the source that supplies the conditional split?

Comment: I tried this and my new column still isn't showing up. Any ideas of what else I could try? I'd rather not have to delete and re-add everything but maybe that's the only option left?

Comment: The button is missing in 2013 version

Answer (score 1):

I have found this happens in other transformations from time to time. The only way I have to consistently fix it, is to delete the data flow connectors and reconnect them, as sometimes they don't seem to get refreshed in SSIS 2008.

Comment: Just tried it and the column is still missing from Available Destination Columns. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is for SSIS 2013: In destination editor, there is button "New..." next to "Name of the table or view". Press it, edit table name in code, press OK. This will drop your current destination table and create new one, with updated columns, which you can map now. Be careful, as this will drop your current destination table.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works but causes all of the Input Column mappings to reset (at least for me, I'm using Visual Studio 2017). I was able to add the new column by going into the Input and Output Properties tab, expanding ADO NET Destination Input, selecting External Columns and clicking the Add Column button. The new field now becomes available in the Destination Column in the Column Mappings tab.

[image: Input and Output Properties tab]

Answer (score 1):

I had few "Union All" components used in my ssis package and that is where new columns were lost.  I had to update it and include new columns in unions and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem with Visual Studio 2015 and "Microsoft OLE DB Povider for SQL Server" (with "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" I didn't have this problem)

Sometimes data flow tasks don't recognize changes.
Adding / removing a column in the source or target is ignored.

For example, deleting and creating a table with different columns is ignored and just fails the run validation.

Close and reopen Visual Studio is the least problematic solution.